# Is it safe to open new IndexedDb transaction from oncomplete callback of the previous one?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

The reason why I need it is for composing multiple (add,put) transactions in a flatMap style. Now I'm wondering if I can init a new transaction from an oncomplete callback of the previous one. It seems to be working, but I can never be sure what it does in production. For instance if you do similar thing from request onsuccess callback, it has a special meaning of transaction continuation.

The question might also be, is `transaction#oncomplete` method invocation a signal that transaction completed OR is it when `transaction#oncomplete` returns?

I'd have to do some load tests to figure that out myself, In simple test cases it works and it looks the transaction end is `transaction#oncomplete` method invocation, but if I started to use it heavily, there seemed to be some write lock starvations that made me think about this.

Comment: I think when the transaction is complete, the js engine calls transaction.oncomplete. Why are you waiting for one transaction to complete before starting additional transactions?

Comment: I'm not so sure, at least on webkit (PhantomJS). I just need to compose multiple transactions, one after another. Each one starts only if the previous one completed. I'm using IDB rather for bulk operations than for single record operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Starting a second transaction in response to the `"complete"` event of a previous transaction is both correct and the easiest way to reason about the sequencing.

Per spec (section "[steps for committing a transaction](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/IndexedDB/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#steps-for-committing-a-transaction)"):

> [...] Only after the transaction has been successfully written is the "complete" event fired.

As you note, you may see `"success"` events from individual requests, but the overall transaction may abort (index consistency, quota, etc) so waiting for `"complete"` is the right thing to do if you need to reason about the success of the first transaction in subsequent ones.